# Fast algorithm to generate all nonordered permutations of lenght K from N

Tags: algorithm, permutation, combinatorics

I have array of size N, I need to generate all permutations variants of size K from this array. Variants [1 2 3] and [3 1 2] are different. Standard solutions which I found were

1) Just permutations, where I obtain all reordering of the same size as array.

2) Just combinations, where I obtain all combinations of size K from array of size N, but for these algorithms [1 2 6] and [6 1 2] are the same, while I need them to be different.

**Could You help me to find an effective solution?**

I should implement it on Matlab, but I hope I will be able to translate Your solutions from other languages.

Comment: Did you check the answers here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, in any language which can produce all unordered subsets of size K from 1:N, and which can produce all permutations of 1:K, getting all the ordered subsets is as simple as iterating over the subsets and permuting them using every K-permutation.

In Julia language:

```
using Combinatorics, Iterators, Base.Iterators

N = 4
K = 2

collect(flatten(permutations(subset) for subset in subsets(1:N,K)))
```

Gives:

```
12-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2]
 [2, 1]
 [1, 3]
 [3, 1]
 [1, 4]
 [4, 1]
 [2, 3]
 [3, 2]
 [2, 4]
 [4, 2]
 [3, 4]
 [4, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine the two solutions you found. Here's the python code:

```
allPermutations = list()
combinations=getCombinations(arr, K)
for comb in combinations:
    allPermutations.extend(getPermutations(comb))
```

1.`arr` is the input array.

2.`getCombinations` is a function which returns a list of all the combinations in `arr` of size `K`.

3.`getPermutations` returns all permutations of the array given as input.